# wx.StaticLine doesn't always display

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a `wx.StaticLine` separating some buttons in a `wx.GridBagSizer`. When the window initially draws, the `StaticLine` does not show up. Sometimes after a long running task (and I move the window around or something, presumably forcing the frame to be redrawn) it will show up out of nowhere. 
Here is what it looks like:

When window initially draws:

[image: line not showing]

After some long running task (or resize):

[image: line showing]

I create the line with:

```
self.m_staticline1 = wx.StaticLine( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LI_HORIZONTAL )
gbSizer101.Add( self.m_staticline1, wx.GBPosition( 2, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 2 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )
```

and at the end of the `init` I draw with:

```
self.SetSizer( gbSizer1 )
self.Layout()
gbSizer1.Fit( self )
```

I'm not sure if this is significant, but here is how I start the application:

```
app = wx.App(False)
frame = FWHM_Application(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to make it draw initially?

**EDIT:** Here is a working sample program demonstrating the issue:

```
import wx

class Test_Frame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):

        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Test GUI", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( -1,-1 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        # Outer container
        gbSizer_outer = wx.GridBagSizer( 4, 3 )
        gbSizer_outer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        gbSizer_outer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        # Static box for analysis
        analyzeImageBox = wx.StaticBoxSizer( wx.StaticBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Analyze Single Image" ), wx.VERTICAL )

        # Sizer for button/label layout within static box
        gbSizer_single = wx.GridBagSizer( 0, 0 )
        gbSizer_single.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        gbSizer_single.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        self.analyzeImage = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Analyze Image", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 170,45 ), 0 )
        gbSizer_single.Add( self.analyzeImage, wx.GBPosition( 0, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 2 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_staticline1 = wx.StaticLine( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LI_HORIZONTAL )
        gbSizer_single.Add( self.m_staticline1, wx.GBPosition( 1, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 2 ), wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.plotX = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Plot X", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 70,35 ), 0 )
        gbSizer_single.Add( self.plotX, wx.GBPosition( 2, 0 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.plotY = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Plot Y", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 70,35 ), 0 )
        gbSizer_single.Add( self.plotY, wx.GBPosition( 2, 1 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )


        analyzeImageBox.Add( gbSizer_single, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        gbSizer_outer.Add( analyzeImageBox, wx.GBPosition( 1, 1 ), wx.GBSpan( 1, 1 ), wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( gbSizer_outer )
        gbSizer_outer.Fit( self )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )


app = wx.App(False)
frame = Test_Frame(None)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How are you creating the line?  Do manual calls to `.Layout` have any effect?  Without seeing code it's hard to tell you why yours is malfunctioning.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: did you try calling the `layout` function of the panel or the containing `gbSizer1`?

Comment: I tried calling Layout() on `gbSizer1` (which is the outermost sizer) and on `gbSizer101` (which is the sizer containing the static line) to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: I updated the question with how I start the application, if that helps.

Comment: When you're creating this, what is `self`?  Panel?  Frame?  Sizer?

Comment: `self` is a `wx.Frame`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.SetSizer(gbSizer1)
gbSizer1.Fit(self)
self.Layout()
```

Try calling layout last.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not have any effect.

Comment: I used to notice this with the wx.EVT_SIZE event. Calling layout would have no effect but re-sizing would.

Comment: When I resize the window so that the area with the line is not visible and then back to where it is visible, the line shows up. If I resize without going over that area, it does not change.

Comment: You shouldn't have to, but did you try a self.Refresh() ?

Comment: I updated the question with how I start the application, if that helps.